# Why is the code block failing to identify a line as comment in one of my answers?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482821/1223045) to a question today. To my surprise, I was forced to use `/* ---- */` to highlight a line as a comment in the code block. Using `//` failed on each and every use. Now it's not a big deal but I'm curious to know the reason behind it.

And just to make sure `//` is valid, I checked out other answers too and there it worked as expected.

Interestingly, it seems to be considering the string "row" as a keyword too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is tagged [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), but not [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) (even though it mentions PHP functions like `mysql_fetch_array()`. As a result, your code is being highlighted as SQL, where `//` is not a valid comment delimiter, and words like `with` and `row` are considered keywords.

Adding the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag to the question prevents every code block from being assumed to be SQL.

Comment: Ah..makes sense. Never would have guessed this could be a reason